# Reorder a multi-dimensional array into hierarchy using a value of a child element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to transform a flat multi-dimensional array into a hierarchy by using the `group_parent_id` within the individual arrays as reference.

One annoyance is that I can only work with a sub collection of groups that a user has access to, so while `Test group` is a child itself, it's parent isn't actually in the list due to access rights. So `Test group` would be considered root level from this users perspective

Sadly this falls into recursion which isn't my strong point...

**Input:**

```
$arr = [
    [
        'group_id' => 5,
        'group_title' => 'Test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'group_id' => 6,
        'group_title' => 'Second-level test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 5
    ],
    [
        'group_id' => 7,
        'group_title' => 'Third-level test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 6
    ],
    [
        'group_id' => 8,
        'group_title' => 'Other test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'group_id' => 9,
        'group_title' => 'Second-level other test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 8
    ]
];
```

**Desired output:**

```
$arr = [
    [
        'group_id' => 5,
        'group_title' => 'Test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 2,
        'subgroups' => [
            [
                'group_id' => 6,
                'group_title' => 'Second-level test group',
                'group_parent_id' => 5,
                'subgroups' => [
                    [
                        [
                            'group_id' => 7,
                            'group_title' => 'Third-level test group',
                            'group_parent_id' => 6
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'group_id' => 8,
        'group_title' => 'Other test group',
        'group_parent_id' => 1,
        'subgroups' => [
            [
                'group_id' => 9,
                'group_title' => 'Second-level other test group',
                'group_parent_id' => 8
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I've tried a few different things but I am failing at achieving the desired result required above:

```
function build_group_tree(array $groups, $group_ids = [])
{
    $output = [];

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        if (in_array($group['group_parent_id'], $group_ids)) {
            $children = build_group_tree($groups, $group['group_id']);

            if ($children) {
                $group['subgroups'] = $children;
            }

            $output[] = $group;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

build_group_tree($arr, array_column($arr, 'group_id));
```

This gives me a partial result but doesn't include all the groups.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to iterate over the array, creating a list of references to each `group_id`'s entry in the output array, and then adding children via the reference:

```
$output = array();
$group_ids = array();
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $parent_id = $el['group_parent_id'];
    if (!isset($group_ids[$parent_id])) {
        // must be a top-level element
        $output[] = $el;
        // save a pointer
        $group_ids[$el['group_id']] = &$output[array_key_last($output)];
    }
    else {
        // already exists, $group_ids[$parent_id] points to the entry
        $parent = &$group_ids[$parent_id];
        if (!isset($parent['subgroups'])) {
            // no subgroups array, create one
            $parent['subgroups'] = array();
        }
        // add this entry to the subgroups
        $parent['subgroups'][] = $el;
        // save a pointer
        $group_ids[$el['group_id']] = &$parent['subgroups'][array_key_last($parent['subgroups'])];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 5
            [group_title] => Test group
            [group_parent_id] => 2
            [subgroups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_id] => 6
                            [group_title] => Second-level test group
                            [group_parent_id] => 5
                            [subgroups] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [group_id] => 7
                                            [group_title] => Third-level test group
                                            [group_parent_id] => 6
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 8
            [group_title] => Other test group
            [group_parent_id] => 1
            [subgroups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_id] => 9
                            [group_title] => Second-level other test group
                            [group_parent_id] => 8
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LkgLv)

Note this code uses [`array_key_last`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php) which was only introduced to PHP in version 7.3. If you have an earlier version, use `count($array)-1` in its place.